# how to add polylines(routes from public transport) on postgresql(pgrouting) with GUI

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, network, route

> After searching a several long time... i decide to ask here for help,
>   im currently using ubuntu 12.04(because of compatibility) with
>   postgresql 9.1, postgis2, pgrouting2 and qgis2.2

---

i need to make a system for network adding one by one the lines and their "fixed routes" to the database, with eclipse/c# or something like that, so i can do custom interface to add polyliness into database with a GUI :

- Polylines(routes with name tag or ID, for later use on queries)
- A polyline is composed by 2 routes (one to go and on to back, where the last node of one is the first of the other like a circle)
- Polylines have infinite reverse cost(one way direction).
- Some linestrings might use some of the same nodes of other line.

---

I'm kinda newbie in this GIS world, so a detailed guide would be nice.

i read that each thread should contain exactly one question and its answers, so other parts would go in other threads.

---

EDIT2:

- "lines", mean public transport routes
- i have a network(streets) that i want to extend with public
  transport (PT) routes in another layer
- i want to add one by one because there is no PT info available(lines
  or their routes)

---

EDIT3: i did some research again and see that what i need are polylines for each of my routes

i have a network(streets) like this:
[image]
i want to add polyliness like this:
[image]
and one by one like this (but in the same table/layer, so i can use them on shortest patch query later):
[image]

Comment: So far, it's not clear what you are trying to do. If you say "lines", do you mean public transport routes? Or are you trying to create a routable network for car routing?

Comment: hi @underdark actually i follow your guide [link](http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/) but it give me some problems in windows... between i mean public transport routes, i want a way to add them one by one(node per node if needed).

Comment: Please edit your question with additional detail: Do you already have some network which you want to extend with public transport (PT) routes? In which format do you have the PT route data? Why do you want to add them one by one instead of importing them all at once?

Comment: hi again @underdark i dont have any network with PT,i want to add them one by one because in my country there is none(on google maps or openstreetmap and openrouteservice only works on Europe) but if there is a better way then it would save me a lot of time, there are 126.

Comment: If you answer my questions, maybe someone can help.

Comment: So what you actually want to do is change path finding costs at public transportation routes ? like there is PT route from a,b,c to d ,but length wise shortest path would be a to d ,but you want results be a,b,c,d ? correct?